# HTML/Shellcode.Gen HTML Script Virus

Tags: firefox, anti-virus, virus, virus-removal

My computer has been infected with the HTML/Shellcode.Gen HTML Script Virus. How could this be affecting Firefox, and how should I remove it completely?

I currently have Avira AntiVir installed, and it quarantined the virus as expected. However, ever since it was quarantined, Firefox has not been displaying page styles. Why is this, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

It is a malware. Check this : [HTML/Shellcode.Gen - Malware](http://www.avira.com/en/threats/section/fulldetails/id_vir/3676/html_shellcode.gen.html)

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how it shows in FF?

Comment: OK, this was happening to a friends PC [away] and I tried Googling it when I got home with no useful results. So no, no screenshot at the moment.